# Setting up forked-daapd

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, daap

I'm setting up forked-daapd to stream music from my laptop to my phone.
The way I'm doing it, I couldn't use a specific command `/etc/forked-daapd.conf`.

[image: terminal]

As I have researched, I only see people doing that one command. I don't know what to do next.

Comment: ... that's a configuration file, not a program.  You are probably trying to configure it, and need to edit that file with a text editor and `sudo` privileges, not try and execute the file as you just tried to do.

Comment: Is the installation done according to instructions, see https://github.com/ejurgensen/forked-daapd/blob/master/INSTALL

(Check the description for LONG version also)